# Mapping Java classes using Hibernate: How can I map a list of its own objects inside the class

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

Using Hibernate and JPA I want to map a class which contains a list of its own objects, something like:

```
public class Category{
     private List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

I am trying to do this by using:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "category")
```

but when I try this I get the following error:

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: my.domain.name.Category.category in my.domain.name.Category.subCategories
```

Comment: What you want to do is called "Self referencing entity". Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3393662/870122

Comment: yep that was exactly my case, but i am getting this error now : Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Category {

    @ManyToOne
    private Category superCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "superCategory")
    private List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
}
```

The problem in your example is that there is no such property `category` in your class.

Comment: i tried that and i am getting this error now : Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

Comment: @dave do you have any other exceptions from the stack trace? You do of course need the `@Entity` annotation on the `Category` class and I assume there are other attributes being mapped that you didn't include in the original question

Comment: @dave examine the stack trace for the root cause exception. Can I suggest that you accept my answer for this question (your mapping issue is resolved) and create a new question if necessary to get assistance with this new exception.

Answer (score 1):

The [mappedBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy%28%29) attribute of the `@OneToMany` annotation refers to the property name of the association on the owners side. Apparently, there's no attribute named `category` in your `Category` class.