# How to annotate entity in Hibernate that has set of entities of the same type

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have 2 tables. The second table contains two FK to the first one (the meaning is that user can have a team of other users).

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
                usr_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                usr_login VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
);

CREATE TABLE user_team (
        utm_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        usr_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        manager_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT utm_usr_fk FOREIGN KEY (usr_id)
                REFERENCES "user" (usr_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        CONSTRAINT utm_manager_fk FOREIGN KEY (manager_id)
                REFERENCES "user" (usr_id)  ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Can I write some annotation mapping in User class to have set of users (team)?
For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany ??????????????????????
    private List<User> team;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3393662/738746

Comment: As I understand there is one table in this example. But I have two tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id") })
```

But `user_team` will be without `utm_id` column. Is it critical?

Comment: I tried to change the place of usr_id and manager_id. After that it worked once, but now the list is empty. I don't know what is the problem. @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id") })

Comment: This is works for me:   @JoinTable(name = "user_team", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "usr_id") })