# Eclipselink - OneToOne Mapping

Tags: java, sqlite, eclipselink

I am currently developing a little Group Management System and using java 8 with eclipselink and SqlLite.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_GROUP")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String name;
    private List<Permission> permissions;
    private boolean defaultGroup;
    private String prefix;
    private String suffix;
    private int rank;
    private boolean build;
    
    @OneToOne
    private Group inherit;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Group.
     */
    public Group() {

    }
    
    ...Getters Setters
}
```

The Field inherit references to another group that has other permissions, but the current group inherits all permissions from the other group.
How do I work with the field inherit? It is the same Type.
The OneToOne relation gives me following error:

> Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "CONSTRAINT": syntax error)
>
> Error Code: 0
>
> Call: ALTER TABLE T_GROUP ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T_GROUP_INHERIT_ID FOREIGN KEY (INHERIT_ID) REFERENCES T_GROUP (ID)

Comment: I changed the Data Model, because the other class was not needed

Comment: I deleted my response, because it's not relevant to the now edited post...

Comment: What sort of "work" do you want to do with the field `inherit`?

Answer (score -1):

If your question is how to map the self referencing relationship, you can simply use @OneToOne annotation. This is already answered here [JPA: How to have one-to-many relation of the same Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type)