# Design of DTO from Model for an API

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api-design

I am designing an API using Spring boot for some social network backend. My current model looks like this:

```
public class User {

    private long id;
    private String handle;
    private String name;
    private List<User> followers;
    private List<User> following;

    // Getters setters etc
```

Now, I have created DTO which closely resembles above structure. My problem is that sometimes I want to return exactly what's above (which is fine) but sometimes, I don't want that.

For example when someone is only interested in finding followers of user, I don't want to include followers and following (I am simply interested in `id`, `handle` and `name` so computing `followers` and `following` for all of those users would be an incredible waste of resources).

In my current implementation those fields are returned with `null` values, which I don't think is a great idea. Should I create a separate DTO without those lists with just `id`, `handle` and `name`? Or is there more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think is more elegant if you create another layer in your api where you can make a request the user by id to get only partial values, no have sense if you get all values only for get one value from the DTO response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a controversial issue. If you don't want to create separate dto there are several ways to do it. It depends on what data access approach you are going to use:

Using Spring Data JPA it is possible to return an entity in projection. You just need to add an additional constructor to your entity:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("select new User(u.id,u.name) from User u")
    List<User> findAllUserItems();
}
```

Or same using JPA EntityManger:

```
    public List<User> findAllUserItems() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("select new User(u.id,u.name) from User u", User.class)
                .getResultList();
    }
```

If you wonder about unnecessary null fields and you are using Jackson, it is possible to configure to ignore null fields. For Spring Boot:

```
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=non_null
```

Or with Java config:

```
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder objectMapperBuilder() {
        Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
        builder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return builder;
    }
```

Or for not Spring Boot project:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(converter());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpMessageConverter converter() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(objectMapper);
    }
}
```

Also, if you going to use Hibernate Session. To map directly to dto you may use `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`:

```
  public List<UserDto> findAllUserItems() {
            return session.createQuery("select u.id as id,u.name as name from User u")
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(UserDto.class))
                    .list();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can try like this.

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<User> followers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<User> following;

    // Getters, Setters etc....
}
```

Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type) may be helpful.

Comment: How does this answer the question exactly? The OP wants to know how he can prevent certain fields from being returned in his REST API using DTOs, while your solution is just an entity?