# EntityNotFoundException on save for wrong composition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I found weird Hibernate behavior that I can not understand.

Let's say I have class **A** (was inspired with this question [JPA: How to have one-to-many relation of the same Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type))

```
@Entity
public class A {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT")
    private A parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<A> children;

    // Getters, Setters, etc...
}
```

Also, say we have Spring JPA Repository

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {}
```

And test class where magic happens

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:spring/applicationContext-test.xml" })
public class ATest {

    @Autowired
    private ARepository aRepository;

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        A parent = new A();
        parent.setName("I am Parent: 121_1001_21");
        parent.setId("121_1001_21");

        A son = new A();
        son.setName("I am Son: 121_1001_31");
        son.setId("121_1001_31");
        son.setParent(parent);

        A daughter = new A();
        daughter.setName("I am Daughter: 121_1001_32");
        daughter.setId("121_1001_32");
        daughter.setParent(son);
        // daughter.setParent(parent);// yes, I'm intentionally creates wrong hierarchy

        parent.setChildren(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(daughter, son)));// order of elements in set matters!

        son.setChildren(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(daughter)));

        aRepository.save(parent);
    }    
}
```

So the hierarchy is following:

```
Parent (121_1001_21) 
  Son (121_1001_31) 
    Daughter (121_1001_32) 
  Daughter (121_1001_32)
```

But this test fails on saving entity with

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: 
Unable to find com.orga.pcom.om.core.entity.productorder.A with id 121_1001_31
```

After hours of debugging I found that Hibernates tries to load linked entities and load it in this way:

```
Parent (121_1001_21) 1st load
  Son (121_1001_31) 3rd load (this entity loading is fail!)
    Daughter (121_1001_32) 2nd load
  Daughter (121_1001_32) 2nd load
```

and fails! So, the questions are:

1. Why Hibernate loads something while it saves something? :)
2. What is the best way to fix this issue?

Comment: what is the point of `setId()` ? You have that field marked as being generated! so it is saved under a different id. But then if you looked at the JPA providers log you'd see that ...

Comment: ok, removed @GeneratedValue. The problem is still there

Comment: right, and when you debug it, showing what INSERT statement is issued? and what SELECT is issued for the find ?

Comment: Well, is that matters here is the log of invocations https://pastebin.com/5Aj0aPPz