# Ebean model mapping itself with @OneToMany

Tags: java, playframework, orm, ebean

I'm currently creating a ebean model `User` which trying to map back to itself. Since the `User` and it's child uses the data structure, my idea is to reuse them without creating a new model / table.

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User parent;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<User> childs = new ArrayList<>();

    ....
}
```

And the database schema looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
id CHAR(7),
email CHAR(255),
parent_id CHAR(255),
...
);
```

The mapping `@ManyToOne` from child to parent is working fine. But i get the error below when running the app with the `@OneToMany` mapping introduced:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error on models.User.childs  Can not find mappedBy property [user] in [models.User]
```

I suspect ebean was trying to look for `user_id` in `user` table, which in fact it was linked by `parent_id` as screen in the database structure.

Any idea if this even supported by ebean or is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA: How to have one-to-many relation of the same Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type)

Comment: Either you are using the JPA API, or you are using EBean. You can't use both APIs. Decide

Comment: An `ElementCollection` is for elements of non-entity types. Do you have that? Nope. "mappedBy" should point to a field in the element class ... so is there really a field called "user" in `User`? Nope.