# Mapping between class and object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapping, hibernate-mapping

I have a class named theme , and a theme can have sub_themes.
i want to do mapping between the class  theme and the object sub_theme of type theme.

Example :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "themes")
public class Theme {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Id", nullable = false)
    @Getter @Setter private Long id;
    @Column(name = "titre", nullable = true)
    @Getter @Setter private String titre;


    @Getter @Setter private Theme sub_theme;


    public Theme() {
    }

}
```

How can i do mapping between theme and sub_theme, and how to persist a theme with its sub themes ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderTerekhov for the example :) .

Answer (score -1):

You need to add annotation @ManyToOne on sub_theme field.