# Spring Data JPA SelfReference Entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a trouble with an Self-Relationship Entity.

I have configured my entity following this [post](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-self-join-annotations-one-to-many-mapping/)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICIO")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Servicio extends AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_seq_servicioedesk")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq_servicioedesk", sequenceName = "SERVICIOEDESK_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID_SERVICIO")
    private Integer idServicio;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICIO_PADRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_SERVICIO")
    private Servicio servicioPadre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "servicioPadre",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<ServicioEdesk> serviciosHijos;
```

I was reading for a long time and I found similar questions that were resolved using a similar configuration to mine:

- [JPA: How to have one-to-many relation of the same Entity type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type)

However, I always get an Stackoverflow error when I try to retrive elements from my database:

```
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2d4a3e13<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@1b37fbec>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@4a22e4d7<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@3c54ddec>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@d8835af<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@7b9088f2>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@16681017<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@73a6cc79>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@6aae0e6f<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@183fc2fa>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@37775bb1<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@6a567f7b>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@7b9e25bd<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@6a2d867d>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@2d206a71<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@66f5b8fe>
    [WARN ] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.423 [] LoadContexts - HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@37e7c4cc<rs=oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet@bb3ecfe>
    [ERROR] 2019-05-14 09:49:31.425 [] TransactionInterceptor - Application exception overridden by rollback exception
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:776) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:897) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1034) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3820) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3867) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1502) ~[ojdbc7-11.2.0.2.0.jar:12.1.0.1.0]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:449) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:693) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1933) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:559) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
        at com.*.*.entidad.ServicioEdesk.hashCode(ServicioEdesk.java:21) ~[classes/:?]
        at com.*.*.entidad.ServicioEdesk.hashCode(ServicioEdesk.java:21) ~[classes/:?]
        at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:611) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
        at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:219) ~[?:1.8.0_144]
```

Comment: It seems the problem is in another place. Please show `hashCode` method

Comment: I forgot implement my hashCode. I have implemented using Lombok and it works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it excluding this fields from my `HashCode`.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SERVICIO")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"idServicio", "nombreServicio", "palabrasClave"})
public class Servicio extends AuditableEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "my_seq_servicioedesk")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "my_seq_servicioedesk", sequenceName = "SERVICIOEDESK_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ID_SERVICIO")
    private Integer idServicio;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "SERVICIO_PADRE", referencedColumnName = "ID_SERVICIO")
    private Servicio servicioPadre;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "servicioPadre",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Servicio> serviciosHijos;
```