# Persist @ManyToOne relation based on condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose we have an Employee entity, this entity has a reflexive relation (relation with itself). The kind of the relation is `@ManyToOne` mapping meaning, multiple Employee are supervised by only one "Boss" (who's also an Employee). Also Employee entity has relation with a Company entity.

Multiple Employee work for only one Company (@ManyToOne) and a Company know his boss (@OneToOne)

****Question :****

How can we persist this @ManyToOne and @OneToOne relation based on condition (criteria) ?
We can assign (persist) a Boss to an Employee only if they work for the same company. And we can assign an Employee to a company only if he's the boss (means he hasn't supervisor (NULL)).

I guess there are many solution like using @Query, @Prepersist , @Filter, Do the checking in the service but how and which one is better for this case.

Comment: This post might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393515/jpa-how-to-have-one-to-many-relation-of-the-same-entity-type

Answer (score 0):

It can be achived using the below ,

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private A parent;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private Collection<A> children;

    // Getters, Setters, serialVersionUID, etc...
}
```

to check the relations, here's an driver code of MainApplication.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    EntityManager em = ... // from EntityManagerFactory, injection, etc.

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    A parent   = new A();
    A son      = new A();
    A daughter = new A();

    son.setParent(parent);
    daughter.setParent(parent);
    parent.setChildren(Arrays.asList(son, daughter));

    em.persist(parent);
    em.persist(son);
    em.persist(daughter);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

if I set `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` on both of those annotations, I could safely persist one of the entities and ignore the others. Say I persisted parent in my transaction. The JPA implementation traverses parent's children property because it is marked with `CascadeType.ALL`. The JPA implementation finds son and daughter there. It then persists both children on my behalf, even though I didn't explicitly request it.